# RMarkdown will not render from Rscript with sqlite connection

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr, r-markdown

I am unable to render Rmarkdown documents with `Rscript` if they have `dplyr` SQLite calls in them. Take this MWE (`test.Rmd`) which calls for a table in a local copy of the `dplyr::lahman_sqlite()` table.

````
---
title: "TestFile"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
lahman <- src_sqlite("lahman.sqlite")
```

```{r}
tbl(lahman, "Batting")
```
````

In a live R console session I can call `rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")`, and this document is built as expected. But if I call `Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")'` on the command line, I get the following error:

```
Quitting from lines 12-13 (test.Rmd)
Error in UseMethod("db_query_fields") :
  no applicable method for 'db_query_fields' applied to an object of class "SQLiteConnection"
Calls: render ... make_tbl -> structure -> op_base_remote -> db_query_fields
```

I've attached my sessionInfo below, but I've duplicated this error on OS X as well as Ubuntu.

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.5.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.5     digest_0.6.9    assertthat_0.1  R6_2.1.2        DBI_0.4-1       formatR_1.4     magrittr_1.5    evaluate_0.9   
 [9] RSQLite_1.0.0   stringi_1.1.1   rmarkdown_0.9.6 tools_3.3.1     stringr_1.0.0   Lahman_4.0-1    yaml_2.1.13     htmltools_0.3.5
[17] knitr_1.13      tibble_1.0
```

Comment: add a `requireNamespace("RSQLite")` after the `dplyr` `library()` call

Comment: @hrbrmstr the error is still there. And loading the dplyr library already loads that namespace anyways.

Comment: On the other hand, explicitly calling `library(RSQLite)` does, in fact work. Strange that Rscript is messing with namespace calls...

Answer (score 3):

The problem comes from the fact that when using `Rscript` the `methods` package is not loaded. It's therefore required to load it explicitly by adding `library(methods)` in the setup chunk for instance.